# Error in user defined functions with Gp/Pari

Tags: function, pari

I'm trying to work on learning the Gp Pari programing language, and I'm working through project Euler problems and I can't seem to get it to compile right :( It's supposed to calculate a list of all Fibonacci numbers of size less than some input n.

here's the code,

```
Euler_2(n) = 
(
x  = 0;
y = 0;
fib = listcreate(n);
listput(fib,1);
listput(fib,1);
a = True;
while(a, 
{if( x > n,
a = False;
);
x = fib[#fib] + fib[#fib-1];
listput(fib,x);
}); \\ end the while loop
)\\ end the function
```

I'm completely new at this language (I know a fair amount of python). Any helpful comments would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged C? Anyways, IIRC, gp expects functions to be on one line, and you have to put a backslash at the end of each line to continue it if splitting it up into multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the code with braces, not parentheses, to use multiple lines. (You can also use line-ending backslashes, as Shawn suggests in a comment, but that gets old fast.) A quick code review:

```
Euler_2(n) = 
{
  \\ always declare lexical variables with my()
  my(x = 0, y = 0, fib = List([1, 1]), a = 1);
  while(1, \\ loop forever 
    x = fib[#fib] + fib[#fib-1];
    listput(fib,x);
    if(x > n, break);
  ); \\ end the while loop
  Vec(fib); \\ not sure what you wanted to return -- this returns the list, converted to a vector
} \\ end the function
```

Comment: Worth noting that PARI has a built in function for Fibonacci numbers - fibonacci.

Comment: @Andrew Indeed! I thought it was worth going through the motions to show how things are done. If the interest is specifically in the Fibonacci sequence, there are [a dozen other ways](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#PARI.2FGP) of implementing it at Rosetta Code aside from the built-in function.